# Invalid syntax with spacing my list

Tags: python, syntax

I'm getting a invalid syntax with def spread_row()

I have a text file and it works fine in that but when i copy it into the final coding, it  won't work. Help?

What I'm trying to do is make a 3x3 grid of random 1's and 0's. The code is incomplete so some of the coding doesn't so anything yet.

```
##variables to control all the games
##number of games played and points collected in total
games_so_far = 0
total_points = 0

## FOR ONE GAME
## variables that will be used for one single game
max_change = 0

## SUBROUTINES AND FUNCTIONS

import random

def invite_to_play():
  play = raw_input("Would you like to play " + ask_again + "? (y/n): ")
  if play == "y" or play == "Y":
    play_response = True
  else:
    play_response = False
  return play_response

def computer_play():
  computer = raw_input("Would you like that the computer also plays? (y/n): ")
  if computer =="y" or computer =="Y":
    computer_response = True
  else:
    computer_response = False
  return computer_response

def ask_user_int(question):
  response = raw_input(question)
  while not (response.isdigit()):
    print "Your input must be an integer number"
    response = raw_input(question)
  return int(response)

def generate_random_number(dim):
  ## Generate a board of 0's and 1's, up to the size set in "dim"
  return [random.randint(0,1) for i in range(dim)

def spread_row():
  ## Spaces the numbers evenly
  for dat in data:
        print "     ".join(map(str, dat))
  return data

def stop_max_changes()
  print "No more changes, the game is over!"
  return

def program_evaluates_board(numbers):
  ## Evaluates the rows and cols to see if they are even or odd
  row1 = sum(data[0])
  col1 = sum(row[0] for row in data)
  row2 = sum(data[1])
  col2 = sum(row[1] for row in data)
  row3 = sum(data[2])
  col3 = sum(row[2] for row in data)
  if row1%2 == 0:
    print "False"
  else:
    print "True"
  return 


## TOP LEVEL


print 'Welcome to the "An odd matrix" game' + \
      "====================================="

games_so_far = 0

wants_to play = invite_to_play("")
computer = computer_play()



## LOOP TO PLAY MORE GAMES
while wants_to_play:
  games_so_far = games_so_far + 1

  num = ask_user_int("Size of board (between 3 and 6 inclusive): ")
  dim = int(num)

  data = [random_row(dim) for i in range(dim)]

  spread_row()

  print "The board is"
  print "-------------"

  print "\n(initial board)"

  print "\n         Col 0   Col 1   Col 2"

  max_changes = ask_user_int("How many changes would you like to do?" + \
                       "\n > 0 and <= 2: ")
  changes_so_far = 0
```

Comment: Are you using spaces and tabs?  (That's not a good thing.)  You should be able to tell with `python -t file.py`.

Comment: I"m using spaces. What should I put instead?

Comment: This may not be your ultimate error, but you are saying `for dat in data` without declaring `data` in your function. It looks like you should be passing `data` in there and then returning something to your main function, such as `data = spread_row(data)`.

Comment: As long as you're consistent with your use of spaces per block then you should be fine.  It's also recommended to use 4 spaces instead of a tab anyway.

Answer (score 1):

---

first of all , you missing a ":"

```
def stop_max_changes():  # missing : there
```

second, why there is a space in this return value ?:

```
wants_to play = invite_to_play("")  # why space here ?
```

third, you are missing a right bracket

```
def generate_random_number(dim):
  ## Generate a board of 0's and 1's, up to the size set in "dim"
  return [random.randint(0,1) for i in range(dim)
```

pls past full code , I can make full diagnose here ..

Comment: That is the full code, I'm not not finish writing the rest yet. I"m fixing all the errors everyone is catching but even so, there is still a invalid syntax in def spread_row()

Comment: @user1870196: no, there's a missing `]` in `return [random.randint(0,1) for i in range(dim)` before it,  `def spread_row():` by itself is fine.

Comment: @user1870196: this isn't a guessing game.  Post exactly the code you're having trouble with, and the traceback.  After fixing the missing `:`, the extra space in `wants_to play` and adding the extra ']`, your code gives me no syntax errors.